# ComboBox in a Grid does not fill a grid's cell width

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, datagridcell

I have a `ComboBox` in a `Grid` along with several text boxes.
The `Grid` is defined like this:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,10,0,0" ColumnSpacing="5">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!-- All of the text boxes -->
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="8" Text="Combo" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="9" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.ComboText}" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ComboItems}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

Note that I have added in `HorizontalContentAlignment`. This has no effect in making the combo fill the `Grid`, and it still looks like this:

[image]

How can I make the `ComboBox` fill the width of the `Cell`, equally with the other `TextBox`es?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ComboBox in a Grid does not fill a grid's cell width

[`HorizontalContentAlignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment) is used to make horizontal alignment of the control's **content**. If you want to make ComboBox fill a gird cell please set [`HorizontalAlignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment) as `Stretch`.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="9" 
Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.ComboText}" 
ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ComboItems}" 
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

Comment: Thanks, sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes!